# REGEXP_REPLACE guidance

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb

I've been trying to mass remove spammy links from posts on Wordpress on bulk  like the following:

`<a style="text-decoration: none" href="/price-of-xenical-at-pharmacy">.</a>`

They reside in the wp_posts table under the post_content column.  I was attempting to do it via a wild card of adding % within the href tag,  because all the URL's are different but the anchor ( full stop ) and the inline styling is the same.

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content,
    '<a style="text-decoration:none" href="%">.</a>',
    '.');
```

I have since been told that SQL doesn't support what I'm trying to do ( or at least the way I'm doing it ).

I'm using MariaDB which apparently supports [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/),  so I'm looking for some guidance on what SQL Query and REGEX I would need to mass remove these links but leave all the other content intact.

Any help greatly appreciated,   The Aim is to remove the above strings,  or replace with a blank space

## UPDATE

Example post content, last link being the type I need to remove.  :

```
    <h2>Warranty</h2>
<span style="font-size: small"> </span>

<span style="font-size: small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, non risus bibendum quis morbi, duis elit porttitor semper, ante augue at consectetuer elit lectus est, nascetur neque consequuntur donec turpis. Cursus ullamcorper posuere massa interdum, rhoncus blandit, vitae in etiam justo lectus eu fames. Dolor quam dicta wisi class duis. Eleifend sagittis, scelerisque convallis consectetuer sed non aptent. Velit tristique vulputate proin, ipsum diam aliquam. Nibh sit vitae et m</span>

&nbsp;

<a href="https://www.example.com/wp-content/image.jpg"><img class="alignright size-full wp-image-56" title="image" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/image.jpg" alt="image" width="280" height="280" /></a><a style="text-decoration: none" href="/price-of-xenical-at-pharmacy">.</a>
```

Comment: Tim's answer is somehow right it only needs some changes in arguments. Use `REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '<a style="text-decoration:none" href="[^"]*">\\.</a>', '.')`

Comment: @revo I'm not sure what the OP means by putting a literal dot inside the anchor tag, but it makes no sense, because then the OP would not really be complaining about spamming.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's from spamming. OP doesn't have anything to do with it and from their own attempt it seems they want to replace it with a single dot.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Dot is not regex. See this `<a style="text-decoration: none" href="/price-of-xenical-at-pharmacy">.</a>`

Comment: Got it,   This worked : 

UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = 
REGEXP_REPLACE(`post_content`, '<a style="text-decoration:none" href="[^"]*">\\.</a>', '.')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove all anchor tags, but retain the text which was wrapped in the tags, then try using this pattern:

```
<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>
```

Then, replace with just the first capture group.  There is not much to say about the pattern except that we use `(.*?)` to capture the content in between the anchor tags.  The `.*?` is significant, and tells the regex engine to stop at the *first* closing tag.  Otherwise, if we just used `(.*)`, it would potentially consume across multiple anchor tags, should they exist in your column.

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE('<a style="text-decoration:none" href="[^"]*">BLAH</a>',
        '<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>', '$1');
```

The above query outputs `BLAH`.

If you instead want to just strip off all anchor tags, then use this:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE('<a style="text-decoration:none" href="[^"]*">BLAH</a>',
        '<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>', '');
```

Comment: I think im missing something i've tried using this : 'UPDATE wp_posts
  SET post_content = 
  REGEXP_REPLACE('<a style="text-decoration:none" href="%">.</a>',
        '<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>', '$1');
'

But thats replacing ALL content with $1" ,  so its basically removing all content from the mentioned column ( post_content )

I tried using a direct copy of your example,  but it didnt do anything

Comment: I also tested my answer, and this is not the behavior I saw.  It only touched the anchor tags.

Comment: This has just worked for over a 1000 entries : 

UPDATE `wp_posts`
  SET `post_content` =
  REGEXP_REPLACE( post_content, '<a style="text-decoration:none" href="(.*?)">.</a>', '.' );

Just have to find out why it hasnt found the rest of them :)

Comment: Now you are describing a different problem.  Use my regex pattern to flag non matching records, e.g. `WHERE post_content NOT REGEXP '<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>'`

Comment: It seems the bit i posted above,  worked on the fields which had no other content surrounding the the link.

Comment: I've updated my original post with an example of the data.  I'm just getting myself confused and going around in circles, I've tried your original code again to be sure and ever time it removes ALL content and leaves $1 behind.

Comment: Re-reading your reply,  I'm not sure you understood what I wanted,   the anchors are all a full stop as such in my example,   however the URL's are all different so need to be wildcarded. 

Ultimately wanting to capture the whole link and remove it.

Comment: '$1' is for MySQL 8. For MariaDB use '\\1'. Not sure if it can be configured somewhere.

Comment: @revo Do you care to _not_ drop comments like this under other people's answers, when you have already raised your concerns in earlier comments?

Comment: Comments like what? asking to edit to provide the right answer? why shouldn't I  say it?